# Ansible synchronize module returning 127

Tags: ansible, nagios

I'm finding the ansible synchronize module keeps failing with error 127, it blames python but other commands are having no issue, I've got the latest module from ansible-galaxy

```
fatal: [HostA]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}
```

In the playbook I have

```
- ansible.posix.synchronize:
    archive: yes
    compress: yes
    delete: yes
    recursive: yes
    dest: "{{ libexec_path }}"
    src: "{{ libexec_path }}/"
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=check_dhcp"
      - "--exclude=check_icmp"
```

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
timeout = 10
fact_caching_timeout = 30
host_key_checking = false
ansible_ssh_extra_args = -R 3128:127.0.0.1:3128
interpreter_python = auto_legacy_silent
forks = 50
```

I've tried removing the ansible_ssh_extra_args without success, I use this when using apt to tunnel back out to the internet because the remote hosts have no internet access.

I can run sync manually without an issue, pre ansible I used to call rsync using:

```
sudo rsync -e 'ssh -ax' -avz --timeout=20 --delete -i --progress --exclude-from '/opt/openitc/nagios/bin/exclude.txt' /opt/openitc/nagios/libexec/* root@" . $ip . ":/opt/openitc/nagios/libexec"
```

I'm synchronising from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 14.04

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, a way to debug the synchronize or a way to call rsync manually?

Comment: It might be that on remote host just a symlink is missing, something like `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Both files already exist, I think this is a false alarm because all other tasks work just not syncronize but I'm not sure how to debug/resolve it
/usr/bin/python -> python2.7
/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4